# how to share one connectionstring in multiple projects within one solution

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a project within my solution aimed to store my model.ecmx file for EF. This is not the solution's start up project. This project has an `App.Config` file in it.

I have another `App.Config` file in the solutions start up project.

The connection string is defined in both `App.Config files`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Have a global config file and store it there. (OR) have the connection string in `machine.config`

Comment: When you run your solution only the `App.config` file of the start up project will be used. The rest will be ignored, so you only need to have the connection string in your start-up project (you cannot set a class library as startup project). The only reason to have the connection string in another file is that there are more than one possible start-up projects (two different appssharing the same EF model), or when you have separate test projects. In the latter case, the test project's config will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each project can use the same `App.config`, you could simply have a single copy in one project, and include it in the others as a "link", instead of a unique file.

Do include a file as a link, just keep one copy of it across your projects, and then go to each project and do "Add" -> "Existing File". When selecting the file, drop down the "Add" button instead of clicking it, and choose to add as link:

[image: Add as Link]

If they can't share the same App.config, you can use the syntax to use a separate config file for the connection strings, and then include *that* file as a link.

Example of second option:

Main app.config:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="other.config">
</connectionStrings>
```

Note that the `connectionStrings` element above must be completely empty when using `configSource`.

Then other.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
   ....
</connectionStrings>
```

This pattern can be used for many config sections, not just `connectionStrings`.

---

Or, Rahul notes another great option; you could define the connection string at a higher level, such as `machine.config`. That might make deployment a little more complex, but works more simply.